# node.js app running using forever inaccessible after a while

Tags: node.js, socket.io, forever

I have a node.js server and a java client communicating using socket.io. I use this api https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client for the java client. I am using [forever module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)
to run my server.

Everything works well but after some time , my server becomes inaccessible and I need to restart it, Also, most of the times i need to update/edit my node.js server file in order to make my server work again (restarted). Its been two weeks already and im still keep restarting my server :(.

Has anyone run into the same problem ? and solution or advice please.

Thanks

Comment: What do your logs say when you need to restart? Also, what version of forever are you using?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. The forever doesn't log anything aside from the message "server started" i put using console.log.. I am running 0.9.2 version of forever.

Comment: Try to setup [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to track the state of the forever process. [Here](http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/deploying-nodejs-apps) is a blog post on how to set it up

Comment: Ok i will do it. thanks

Comment: Hi @verybadalloc it seems the forever is running ok. I think the problem is i listening two ports in my server. One for the website and the other for the java client and they are communicating each other using global variables. Do you think this is causing a problem with forever? Maybe the other port is restarting and the other is not.

Comment: Hi did you solve this issue, I have also same issue can you please help me out.